How to make a game loop in javascript?
I'm new to programming and i wanted to make a typing game using html,css and javascript.
I want to create a <p> tag every 5 seconds at the beginning and like decreasing the time every 5 words typed correctly.
The <p> tag is the word that the user has to write correctly.
HTML
<head>
    <title>Type game :D</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content grid">
            <div class="container radius">
                <div class="container-start" id="start-text">
                    <h2 class="start" onclick="gameLoop()">Start</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="words grid" id="wordSpawner">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container rules">
                <h1 class="text-h1">RULES</h1>
                <p class="text-rules">
                    - Words will randomly appear in the container on the left <br>
                    - They will move from the left border to the right <br>
                    - Write the words before they reach the right border <br>
                    - After every 5 words the game will get harder <br>
                    - Dont forget to have fun! :D
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-par">
                <input type="text" name="" id="inputWord" class="text-game" onclick="keyPressed()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

CSS
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@100;300;400;500;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #add2c9;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

::selection {
    color: lightblue;
    background-color: white;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.content.grid {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
}

.container.radius {
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 14;
    border: 5px solid;
    height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 12rem;
    border-radius: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #faf9f9;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container.rules {
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 17;
    grid-column-end: 23;
    height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 13rem;

}

.text-par {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 13;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text-h1 {
    font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-rules {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.text-game {
    font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

.container-start {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.start {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index: 1000;
}

h2:hover {
    color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.words.grid {
    display: grid;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.spwn-words {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    align-self: center;
    animation: word 4s linear;
}

@keyframes word {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
}

Javascript
var words = ["gatto","cane","calcio","pallavolo","sport","cibo","pizza"];  //7
var startxt = document.getElementById("start-text");
var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputWord");
var p = document.createElement("p");
var spawner = document.getElementById("wordSpawner").append(p);
var typedWord; 
var playing = false;
spawnedWord = words;


function start(){
    startxt.classList.add("hide");
    playing = true;
}

function generateWord(){
    p.classList.add("spwn-words");
    p.style.gridRowStart = randomRow();
    p.textContent = randomWord();
    console.log(p);
}

function keyPressed(){
    inputValue.addEventListener('keydown',(event)=>{
        if(event.key === 'Enter' && playing == true){
            console.log('Enter key pressed!');
            typedWord = inputValue.value;
        }
    });
}

function randomWord(){
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);

    return spawnedWord[n];
}

function randomRow(){
    var nrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    return nrow;
}


function gameLoop(){
    start();
    generateWord();



}

I'm sorry for the code i wrote but as i said i'm a beginner.
I tried like adding a while loop but it didnt work... I tried making a constructor for the  tag but i didnt know how to make it right, I also tried something with "new Date().getTime() / 1000;" but i didnt know how to go further.

Generally a game loop will be quite similar no matter which programming language you use. I think the conceptual ideas will be far more important and once you understand those you can code it in JavaScript as well. There is a thread on StackExchange for this which links to some great articles on what to do when (and simple vs. more advanced game loops). The code there is not in JavaScript but would easily be portable to it.

For one possible JavaScript implementation in the browser you can checkout this blog post. This will also have an example similar to what you want to do.

In JS you use setTimeout() to do something after a specified period of time. Each time it runs it schedules the next one, reducing the delay each time.

In JavaScript for the Web, the best thing you could do to make a smooth game loop would be using the requestAnimationFrame method.
function gameLoop(){
    start();
    generateWord();

    // request the next animation frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}

For more information, check out the MDN Docs.
I hope this helps.

In JavaScript, to dynamically create <p> tags every 5 seconds and adjust the interval based on user input, you can use setInterval to spawn words at regular intervals and update the interval dynamically.
Use the code below as some sort of guideline:
function gameLoop() {
    start();
    generateWord();

    // Adjust interval based on user input
    if (/* condition for adjusting interval */) {
        clearInterval(intervalID); // Clear previous interval
        intervalID = setInterval(gameLoop, newInterval); // Set new interval
    }
}

// Start the game loop
var intervalID = setInterval(gameLoop, 5000); // Initial interval of 5 seconds

And I believe, you’ll need to define conditions for adjusting the interval based on correct user input. Make sure to declare intervalID outside of the gameLoop function to have access to it globally. This approach allows you to dynamically control the spawning interval based on game progress.
Hope that helps :)

If you clear the interval each time, you might as well use setTimeout :)

I wanna thank you all because your tips really helped me and here's the updated code:


var words = ["gatto","cane","calcio","pallavolo","sport","cibo","pizza"];  //7
var startxt = document.getElementById("start-text"); //"start" text at the beginning of the page/game
var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputWord"); //input for the words to write
var wordSpawner = document.getElementById("wordSpawner"); //container of the words
var starth2 = document.getElementById("starth2");
var typedWord; //typed word XD
var playing = false; //current state of the game: if its currently playing or not
var intervalID; //decides how many seconds for a new word
var countDown; //countdown after clkicking the "start"
var hp = 3; //how many lifes you have before losing
var correctWord = false;
//clearTimeout(intervalId); servira' per generare parole piu' fast ;) 

/*fixare funzione randomrow in modo che 
non possa spawnare una parola sulla stessa riga*/ 



function startGame(){
    startxt.removeChild(starth2);
    playing = true;
    inputValue.focus();
    gameLoop();
    inputValue.addEventListener('keydown',handleEvent);

}

function gameLoop(){
    if(playing){
        generateWord();
        intervalID = setTimeout(gameLoop,2000); //generates a word every 2 seconds
    }
    console.log("current hp: ",hp);
    endGame();
}

function handleEvent(event){
    if(event.key === 'Enter' && playing){
        typedWord = inputValue.value; 
        // console.log("parola scritta :", typedWord);
        checkWord(typedWord);
        if(correctWord){
            inputValue.value = '';
            correctWord = false;
        }
    }
}
    
function checkWord(word){
    var allWords = document.querySelectorAll(".spwn-words");
    allWords.forEach((allWord) => {
        if(allWord.textContent === word){
            wordSpawner.removeChild(allWord);
            correctWord = true;
        }
    }); 
}

function generateWord(){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.classList.add("spwn-words");
    p.style.gridRowStart = randomRow();
    p.textContent = randomWord();
    wordSpawner.appendChild(p); //creates a <p> tag containing a random word and row inside the container for words

    setTimeout(() => {
        if(wordSpawner.contains(p)){
            wordSpawner.removeChild(p);
            hp--;
        }
    }, 4000); //removes word after 4 seconds
    
}

function endGame(){
    if(hp === 0 && playing){
        playing = false;
        while(wordSpawner.firstChild){
            wordSpawner.firstChild.remove();
        }
        var gameOver = document.createElement('h3');
        gameOver.classList.add("info-text");
        gameOver.textContent = 'Game Over :C';
        startxt.appendChild(gameOver);
        inputValue.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEvent);
    }
}

function randomWord(){ 
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    return words[n];
}

function randomRow(){
    var nrow = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    return nrow;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@100;300;400;500;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #add2c9;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    color: black;
}

::selection {
    color: lightblue;
    background-color: white;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.content.grid {
    display: grid;
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
}

.container.radius {
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 14;
    border: 5px solid;
    height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 12rem;
    border-radius: 2.5rem;
    background-color: #faf9f9;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container.rules {
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 17;
    grid-column-end: 23;
    height: 30rem;
    margin-top: 13rem;

}

.text-par {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 13;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text-h1 {
    font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-rules {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.text-game {
    font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

.container-start {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.info-text {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index: 1000;
}

h2:hover {
    color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.words.grid {
    display: grid;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

.spwn-words {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    align-self: center;
    animation: word 4s linear;
}

@keyframes word {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Type game :D</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content grid">
            <div class="container radius">
                <div class="container-start" id="start-text">
                    <h2 class="info-text" onclick="startGame()" id="starth2">Start</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="words grid" id="wordSpawner">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container rules">
                <h1 class="text-h1">RULES</h1>
                <p class="text-rules">
                    - Words will randomly appear in the container on the left <br>
                    - They will move from the left border to the right <br>
                    - Write the words before they reach the right border <br>
                    - After every 5 words the game will get harder <br>
                    - Dont forget to have fun! :D
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-par">
                <input type="text" name="" id="inputWord" class="text-game" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I still have to fix some things (for example words spawning in the same rows) but i think i'm at a good point.
Thank you all again.
